# Sorting on a 2D list

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I have a 2D list that I have created from reading in a txt file. I have written this code to sort the list by the highest value - position 5.

```
sort = list(sorted(sort,key=lambda x: x[5],reverse=True))
for i in range( 0, len( sort ) ):
            print( "Name:",sort[i][0],"\tscore1:",sort[i][1],"\tscore2:",sort[i][2],"\tscore3:",sort[i][3], "\tHighest:",sort[i][5] )
```

The code seems to work apart from that for some reason it put's 10 (the only 2 digit number at the bottom of the list rather than at the top. I have use the max function to attain the highest number and then simply appended it to the end of each list.

Name: B     score1: 6   score2: 1   score3: 3   Highest: 6

Name: Z     score1: 4   score2: 4   score3: 5   Highest: 5

Name: Neil  score1: 4   score2: 1   score3: 3   Highest: 4

Name: fred  score1: 10  score2: 0   score3: 0   Highest: 10

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your input list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you don't actually have numbers, but strings.*

Strings are compared lexicographically—that is, alphabetical order, character by character, the same way you'd sort words in a dictionary. Digits aren't anything special; they're treated just like any other character. So, `"10"` is smaller than `"2"` because the first character of the first string, `"1"`, is smaller than the first string of the second character, `"2"`.

What you probably want to do is store integers (or floats, or some other numeric type) in the first place.

But if you want to store strings and sort by their integer value, you can pass `int` as the sorting key. Or, in your case, `lambda x: int(x[5])` instead of `lambda x: x[5]`.

---

<sub>* For debugging in the future: when you just `print` a value, it can be ambiguous what it is. The number `2` and the string `"2"` both just print out as `2`. It can help to temporarily `print(repr(x))` and/or `print(type(x))` to find problems like this. (You'd get `2` vs. `'2'` and `int` vs. `str`, respectively.) Even the `repr` can still *occasionally* be ambiguous—but this mostly only happens in cases where it usually doesn't matter. Mostly.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the explanation. After trying your method and realising the problem I decided to convert the max to an int before doing the sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `x[5]` seems to be a string. You should try converting it to an `int` by calling `int(x[5])`.

Comment: Many thanks. To rectify the issue I converted max to an int before completing the sort.